# How to construct a turing machine for the following language?

Tags: turing-machines

Any ideas on how to construct a turing machine that recognize the following language?
{   a^2n b^(n^2-3) |    n ≥ 3 }

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck? Are you having trouble conceptualizing an algorithm that will recognize this language? Are you having trouble converting that algorithm into Turing states? What specifically are you stuck on? You can break the problem into two major parts: 1. find `n` from the `a`s, 2. verify you have `n^2-3` `b`s. Does that help? If not, please be more specific in what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Yes the part where i have problem is coneptualizing an algorithm, I dont wan't a complete turing machine just a hint on how to proceed on solving this problem. A thought i made was to add 3 b to the end  and then and have { a^2n b^n^2} then add n c's to the end and have {a^2nb^n2c^n } and then match and delete b's and c's for every 2a until no a's are left.. but this seems to be too complicated

Comment: That will definitely do it. Sounds like you don't need any help to me!